# HQC Duplicated Reed-Muller Codes

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hqc

I'm having trouble with a definition in the [HQC Specification](https://pqc-hqc.org/doc/hqc-specification_2020-10-01.pdf).
From page 25f., in section 2.5.5.:

[image: Decoding the internal Reed-Muller code section]
[image: Decoding the internal Reed-Muller code section (following page)]

What does it mean to duplicate a code? Is it repeating each bit, similar to a repetition code?

Further, I don't understand the type of the function $F$: $\mathbb{F}_2^7 \to 3, 1, -1, -3^7$.
Is this a typo, and it should map to $\{3, 1, -1, -3\}^7$ instead?

What do they mean by

> where we started with transforming each block of three bits $x_1 x_2 x_3$ of the received vector in $(-1)^{x_1} + (-1)^{x_3} + (-1)^{x_3}$

?

Assuming this is the definition of $F$, I don't understand why $F$ takes 7 bits as input, instead of 3.

#### Should $F$ have the type $\mathbb{F}_2^3 \to \{3, 1, -1, -3\}$ instead? (Note the removed $\cdot^7$ and changed input space)

In section 2.5.7. they go through an example with multiplicity of 2 (instead of 3 like above):

[image: Reed-Muller decoding, step 1. page 26]

Is this code equivalent to the concatenation of a repetition code and a Reed-Muller code? (where concatenation is what they define in def. 2.5.1.)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The lead authors are well known coding theory people. I am surprised by the sloppiness in the writing, and cannot make head or tail of it, just like you.

Comment: That's good to know, that I'm not the only one having trouble parsing this :-)